# Scala, common part (intersection) of words in the list using sets

Tags: java, scala, recursion, set, runtimeexception

I want to define function in Scala with recursion which returns set of letters which is present in all words from the list.

For example:

```
    val l = List("rak","krab","krab","bark","mucha","mucha","trakty")
```

Should return something like:

```
    Set('a')
```

[UPDATED] My code looks as follows:

```
    object Program {
        def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

            val l = List("rak","krab","krab","bark","mucha","mucha","trakty")

            def inAll(lista: List[String]): Set[Char] = l match {
                case Nil => Set()
                case n :: Nil => n.toSet
                case n :: n2 => n.toSet & inAll(n2)
            }

            println(inAll(l))
        }
    }
```

While I want to display what function returns by printing the execution of it

```
    println(inAll(l))
```

then I get the **RuntimeException**. I've been searching the Net for hours how to solve this, but I haven't found the answer. I found something like this, but it's not enough.

- http://alvinalexander.com/scala/union-intersection-difference-scala-sets
- http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html

The error I get is:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at sbt.BuildCommon$$anonfun$toError$1.apply(Defaults.scala:2128)
        at sbt.BuildCommon$$anonfun$toError$1.apply(Defaults.scala:2128)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at sbt.BuildCommon$class.toError(Defaults.scala:2128)
        at sbt.Defaults$.toError(Defaults.scala:39)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$runTask$1$$anonfun$apply$46$$anonfun$apply$47.apply(Defaults.scala:769)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$runTask$1$$anonfun$apply$46$$anonfun$apply$47.apply(Defaults.scala:767)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    [error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
```

I think there is something wrong in the line in which I want to recursively intersect all words from a list by calling the function **inAll** with parameter **n2**.

```
    case n :: n2 => n.toSet & inAll(n2)
```

This exception is when I try to run my program, there is no errors when I compile it.

[UPDATED] I compile program using

```
    compile
```

in SBT. And run it by

```
    run
```

also in SBT.

Comment: It is an l (L in lower case).

Comment: Can you share the whole code please, as well as the way you compile it ? Is it a compile-time error or a runtime error ? Most of the stacktrace is about SBT...

Comment: It is a runtime error. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `inAll` function is using `l` to `match` instead of the function's argument `lista`.

This appears would cause a stack overflow or out-of-memory exception and crash the program.

Comment: @mmazepa you probably did not show us the right part of the exception. The exception you submitted is completely irrelevant to what was actually going on. Not saying this to be mean, just to tell you you need to learn to identify what's important in a stacktrace and what's not. In this example, the stracktrace did not really help because it was only about SBT, not about your code